# Can you translate this writing and red seal signature?

Tags: character-identification

[image]Here is an old ink on paper painting - can you identify the red seal signature and the text? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the seal is 常道. Pretty sure it's the painter's name.

余登峨眉，宿于洗象池，夜入被窝，如入凉水中。
癸未四月廿五日，常道

I climbed to the top of the Emei Mountain, and stayed at night in the Xixiang Pond (wash elephant pond).
When I hit the sack at night, it felt like entering cold water.
April 25, 2003. Chang Dao

Comment: Thank you! That is very helpful. I was wondering how you came to the date 2010, as it was believed to be older than this?

Comment: @CryptoTakers Sorry that I made a mistake. I should have double check it before posting the year rather then relying on my memory. It should be 2003 + n * 60, n is any integer you can think of. This is because 癸未 is part of the so called 干支, which can be used to track year within a cycle of 60 years. You can check out the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagenary_cycle) for more information.

Comment: Thank you once again for your brilliant information.  It's very much appreciated that you have taken the time to explain all this.

Comment: “余登峨眉，`夜`宿于洗象池”， 多了一个字

Comment: Thank you for this additional info.

Comment: @imkzh 大意了，已改正。